# Find first zero in array in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to find first zero element in array in matlab. I'm using "find" function to find zero but it didn't giving true answer but it give correct answer for 1.

Comment: This question does not offer a [mcve], and thus has attracted a number of guesses, and it remains unresolved. It should be closed.

Answer (score 12):

`find` should do the trick if used like so:

```
> a = [1 2 3 0 5 6 0 8 9];
> find(a==0, 1, 'first')
ans =  4
```

Let us know if this isn't working (and some additional details about the problem).

[MATLAB find](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html)

Comment: `find(a==0, 1, 'first')`

Comment: There I go not reading the OP's actual question. Thanks, @MattPhillips!

Answer (score 1):

```
>> a = [1 2 3 0 5 6 0 8 9];

>> a=a==0;

>> n=1:length(a);

>> [n out]=max(a./n);

out =

     4
```

Comment: This answer could be improved: Explain what you're doing here, and provide some additional resources for basic matlab operations. If the question isn't worthy of a detailed answer, consider asking him in the comments to further elaborate on his question.

Answer (score 1):

more simple:

```
find(~a,1,'first')
```