# Find first zero row in a 2 column array in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have an array with many rows and two columns. I wish to find the first row for which both entries are zero in the array. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10199109/find-first-zero-in-array-in-matlab) post but am unsure how to adapt the find command for a 2 column array.

Comment: Let a be your matrix, try `find(~(a(:,1)==a(:,2)==0))`

Comment: @pkpkpk Your suggestion fails whenever `a(k,1) == a(k,2)`, but neither is equal to zero.

Comment: @beaker Well said. Should just be `find(~a(:,1) & ~a(:,2))`

Comment: @pkpkpk Hi both. Thank you for your comments. I was doing my own experimenting ad was going to comment that the first command doesn't seem to be working, when I saw the new comments. The new command works a treat. I was just wondering, why is the ~ symbol used here? I thought ~ means 'not',  but we are not saying what these elements are meant to 'not' be...

Comment: The tilde is used for the not operation as you pointed out. The elements are the non-non-zero values, i.e. the 0s.

Comment: @21joanna12 The `~` (logical not) is used as a replacement for `== 0`. In both cases, the `0` elements of the vector will become `1` and all other elements will be `1`. You could write the same line as `find(a(:,1)==0 & a(:,2)==0)`.

Comment: ^sorry, should be "0 elements of the vector will become `1` and all other (nonzero) elements will become **`0`**".